# Postgres run \set from commandline

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run

```
psql -c '\set db_name test'
```

but this never seems to set the variable.

If I first enter `psql` and then run `\set db_name test` it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the parameter `--set` or `-v`, e.g.:

```
psql --set=db_name=test
```

or just

```
psql -v db_name=test
```

To store a value permanently for `psql` you can write the `\set` command into `~/.psqlrc`. (but it's only available in `psql`).

Comment: They both will enter psql which is what I am trying to avoid

Comment: You may use it in combination with `-c`. Note, that these variables are only set for the current session and not permanently.